# Count number of children in limited depth tree

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, parent-child

I have a tree structure in MySQL using a parent_id field for each node. The structure is quite large but only about 8 levels deep. Each node also has a child_counter field.

I'm looking for a performant way to calculate (and update) the number of children each node has (by children I am including children of children etc.), preferably with not too many SQL calls. I don't expect this to be super fast, just good enough.

I'm hoping there might be some way to do a mass update as the algorithm iterates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented something like this before, but not quite. Are you able to store a "depth" integer on each node, to mark their depth in the tree? If so, you could do this with 8 queries, which if properly indexed would be quite reasonable. Something like this I think (don't have mysql handy). You would query from the lowest depth (i.e. 8) upwards:
`UPDATE Node SET child_counter = ((SELECT SUM(child_counter) FROM Node WHERE parent_id = id) + (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Node WHERE parent_id = id)) WHERE depth = x`

Comment: We spent all day playing around with various options before realising your solution was by far the fastest, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

You're currently using an *Adjacency List Model* with additional count column. But actually what you try to get from hierarchical data looks like it could be modeled much easier with the *Nested Set Model*.

Comment: We did consider this approach initially, but it wasn't appropriate at the time. Now that it's appropriate we don't have the time to change the system this substantially...